# Custom fonts c# error

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem when loading custom fonts in winforms with c#.

Below is my implementation:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //font
    {
        PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
        int fontLength = Properties.Resources.ARCADECLASSIC.Length;
        byte[] fontdata = Properties.Resources.ARCADECLASSIC;
        IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontLength);
        Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, fontLength);
        pfc.AddMemoryFont(data, fontLength);
        button12.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], button12.Font.Size);
        button9.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], button9.Font.Size);
        label1.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], label1.Font.Size);
        button5.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], button5.Font.Size);
        button1.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], button1.Font.Size);
        button3.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], button3.Font.Size);
        button4.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], button4.Font.Size);
    }
}
```

It is working but sometimes I have this red cross instead of my text:

[image]

What is the solution to this? Am I going out of scope?

Comment: added image for reference

Comment: I think maybe you need to make your "data" and pfc a static or member

Comment: The Red Cross of failure tells you that the OnPaint() method of a control failed with an exception.  That is a pretty common mishap with PrivateFontCollection.AddMemoryFont(), memory corruption is the usual trouble maker.  I however don't see the standard Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem() call that is responsible for it, a bug that is very, very common since the top Google hit gets that wrong.  There is a very tempting empty line at the bottom of that snippet, we can't see what was there.

Comment: also, you need to keep track of it so you can clean it up, if you allocate memory you need to deallocate it at some point

Comment: Use [AddFontMemResourceEx](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32.addfontmemresourceex) - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183325(v=vs.85).aspx) instead  and [RemoveFontMemResourceEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162921(v=vs.85).aspx) after.